# Proxy settings in npm-yeoman

Tags: node.js, proxy, npm

I am building my angular application using yeoman.

I have set proxies and registry as follows:

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.tcs.com:8080

npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.tcs.com:8080

npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Even after setting proxy as above,while installing

```
npm install grunt-ngmin,
```

I get the following error,

```
npm WARN package.json teamshareangular@0.0.0 No README.md file found!
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-ngmin
npm http 407 http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-ngmin
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
npm ERR! <HEAD><TITLE>Proxy Authorization Required</TITLE></HEAD>
npm ERR! <BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black"><H1>Proxy Authorization Required</H1><HR>
npm ERR! <FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
npm ERR! Description: Authorization is required for access to this proxy</B></FONT>
npm ERR! <HR>
npm ERR! <!-- default "Proxy Authorization Required" response (407) -->
npm ERR! </BODY>
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     at Object.parse (native)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Documents\tools\nodejs\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:235:23)
npm ERR!     at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Documents\tools\nodejs\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\main.js:120:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Documents\tools\nodejs\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\main.js:648:16)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Documents\tools\nodejs\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\main.js:610:14)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:910:16
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Users\\\Documents\\tools\\nodejs\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\\Documents\\tools\\nodejs\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.j
"grunt-ngmin"
npm ERR! cwd C:\nodejs\Teamshare\Teamshareangular
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.7
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.14
npm ERR! type unexpected_token
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\nodejs\Teamshare\Teamshareangular\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

What is to be done for this?

Should I make some other settings in npm?

Please advice.

Comment: May be your proxy doesn't allow anonymous connections, and needs authorization.

Comment: How to overcome that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your proxy needs authentication. If you have proxy in your control then create a user and use the folowing command to configure npm to use your credectials. (Note the user & pass before hostname)

```
$ npm config set proxy http://login:pass@host:port

$ npm config set https-proxy http://login:pass@host:port
```

Answer (score 1):

For various reasons, the most obvious being security, you might want to avoid putting your proxy credentials in clear text into the npm config.

You can however install a local forwarding proxy that offloads the proxy authentication. Personally, I use squid (in combination with [SquidMan](http://squidman.net/squidman/), a few colleagues use [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/). Cntlm has quirks and is unmaintained afaict, but squid works quite well for me.

I run squid on `localhost:4321` and configure npm to connect to `http://localhost:4321`. Squid then authenticates against the corporate proxy with stored, encrypted credentials.